# How to force order in semaphores in java

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm using semaphore to force some order in my program: I  have a main thread and a few sub-threads that are created in the main thread.
In the main thread in every step a clock is ticked then after that I want each sub-thread to run one by one. the order of sub-threads is not important but I want them all to run in each step( and each run only once in every step). 
I've written this code, but the problem is that in some cases in one step on of the sub-threads run several times not letting others to get chance to run ?!

the main thread:

```
     Semaphore okToTick = new Semaphore(3);
     Semaphore okToWork = new Semaphore(0, true);

     int i = 0;

     new TestClass2(0, okToTick, okToWork);
     new TestClass2(1, okToTick, okToWork);
     new TestClass2(2, okToTick, okToWork);

     while(true){

        okToTick.acquire(3);

        System.out.printf("\clock : %s\n", i++);


        okToWork.release(3);

     }
```

and the run() for sub-threads:

```
    semaphores here, passed by cnstr() 
    ID = //passed in by cnstr()    
    isBusy = false; 
    ----------------------------------
    try{
        while(true){

            okToWork.acquire();

            if(!isBusy){
                System.out.println("inside sub " + ID);
                isBusy = true;
            }


            okToTick.release();

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){}
```

I want this result :

```
  clock : 0
  inside sub 1
  inside sub 0
  inside sub 2

  clock : 1

  clock : 2
  ...
```

but sometimes I get this:

```
  clock : 0
  inside sub 1

  clock : 1
  inside sub 0
  inside sub 2

  clock : 2
  ...
```

Comment: A hint: when you release okToTick, the clock might tick. And since you release it immediately after printing, it is not surprising that the clock ticks right away sometimes. You need to wait for all the sub-threads to finish before saying it is ok to tick. Good luck with your homework.

Comment: If you have tasks you want to perform in a particular order, you should do the all in the same thread.  Multiple threads are useful when you have multiple independent tasks which can be performed in any order.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html):

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this topic. Is it possible to make this work using only semaphores?

Comment: You're using a hammer to drive screws. Why don't you learn how to use a screwdriver. It's documented, and I even linked to the javadoc. Click, read, understand, and try something. If you want to use semaphores only, I would use one semaphore per working thread.

Comment: You're right but I have to finish this by tomorrow. And as I understood for using CyclicBarrier you must use a class that implements runnable but I'm forced to used the run method of Thread. Could you please tell me about how I could use semaphores to implement this? What did you mean by using one semaphore per working thread?

Comment: 1) `CyclicBarrier` has no business with `Runnable`; 2) `public class Thread implements Runnable`

Comment: I mean that you could have each thread use its own semaphore, instead of all threads using a single semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

In your case one thread can acquire `okToWork` and release `okToTick`  multiple times before the others even get the opportunity to spin up, ie. thread no. 1 can do up to 3 times  `okTowork.acquire()` -> `okToTick.release()` before the others.

You also print `inside sub x` only once for each thread as you never reset the `isBusy` flag.

You need to differentiate them and the simplest way of doing it using a `Semaphore` is to give a different `okToTick Semaphore` to each Thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "sub-threads" may be acquiring more than one permit from the semaphore, and you are not realizing it in your output since the "inside sub" output only gets printed once (you would see it multiple times if you removed the `if(!isBusy)` surrounding it).  If you don't want each "sub-thread" to acquire more than one permit, remove the outer `while(true)` loop.

```
    okToWork.acquire();

    //if(!isBusy){ Removed to show when this sub-thread is actually acquiring permits
        System.out.println("inside sub " + ID);
    //    isBusy = true;
    //}


    okToWork.release();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even if I remove that if still the problem exists there. In some cases one thread runs several times in one tick! And I must have loop in sub-threads. This is just a part of program. The threads are supposed to run in a loop.